# Git wrongly detects conflicts

Tags: git

Often when I do

```
git pull origin master
```

Git reports conflicts even in files that were modified only in my current branch and not in master. What could be wrong?

Comment: Which files have conflicts? What're the conflicts like? What does `git log <your branch> -- <conflict_file>` and `git log origin/master -- <conflict_file>` echo?

Comment: You are trying to pull origin's `master` into your local branch. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. There are no conflicts really, Git makes them up. I modify one c++ source file in the current branch and try to merge it with the master branch that has changed in the meantime but the particular file in the master branch has not changed. Nevertheless, some of the differences between the original unmodified file and the new version of the file are reported as conflicts.

Comment: @ElpieKay sorry, I can't tell you what git log says because I'm not having this problem at the moment, but I have it often and resolve things manually.

Comment: It's funny how, on the occasion when someone reports this type of behavior, they never are having the problem right now and can never provide the diagnostics to confirm that it's anything more than an observation error on their part.  But they're sure they're right because it "happens all the time".  So good news: since it's a frequent problem, you can just wait until it happens again so you can provide proper diagnostic info.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a `git fetch origin master; git diff --name-status` is helpful to find out which files actually differ.

Answer (score 0):

Switch on master first

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by differences in the encoding settings between team members. Other guys were using the setting recommended on Windows ("config core.autocrlf true" - checking out Windows style and checking in Unix style), while I was checking out and in "as is". Then Visual Studio would convert the Unix line endings to Windows line endings, thus creating these conflicts.